# How would I make the "box" glossy but the image decal on top of it matte without it losing all the color?

Tags: uv, shaders, image

I'm working on a product. I made the box dieline and then made the decal png design and adjusted the UV to fit. I want to make the png decal maintain the color but have a matte finish. I want the box itself to be a "holo" effect so I need it to be glossy. I can't find info on how to do this without losing the detail in the decal (i.e becoming a flat color). Can anyone give me any pointers?[image]

Comment: You could make them two separate objects, or you could use a UV map to separate regions, or you could put the decal on a subset of faces and give the faces different materials.  Depends on whether you want the decal to be partially transparent so that the matte surface shows through

Comment: Is alpha layer a mask of the decal?  Take alpha layer through a color ramp set to constant and use it to drive Roughness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix your background color with the decal in a *Mix Shader*, use the decal alpha as the factor:

[image]